# How do I make my Ubuntu Desktop PC a server?

Tags: server

Can I transform my Ubuntu Desktop installation into a server? I want to test this out, but I do not want to make any permanent changes. How can I host a html web page I have on my PC temporarily?

Comment: You simply install the server you wish to use. Traditionally servers do not have graphical interfaces as desktops are of limited value. If you want a graphical interface use a web based solution such as webmin or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to host a html webpage on your Ubuntu Desktop installation, you can easily do so by installing `apache2`, a web server. More configuration may be needed if you want to host php files.

1. Install `apache2`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apache2
   ```
2. Put your webpage and other files that you want to host in `/var/www/html/`
3. Browse your page at `http://localhost/`

After you're done testing it out, you can remove `apache2` along with any other configuration files with `sudo apt-get purge apache2`.

Comment: But how to point a domain to my server then?

Comment: @NivedKannada - Now you are asking a second question. Configuring servers can be very lengthy and it is better to ask a more specific (new) question.

Comment: Ok. But can I ask about cofiguring questions in this Ubuntu community?

Comment: Basically, (assuming you're using a typical home user setup) you have to port forward and open ports on your firewalls as necessary, and also set up A records to point to your router's WAN IP. As @bodhi.zazen mentioned, it's best to create a new question so this can be answered more specifically.

Comment: @NivedKannada Yes, but, ask a specific question. Otherwise see https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ you can not possibly expect us to re-type that guide here in response to a broad question.

Answer (score 1):

Can either try installing the apache webserver, if that's all you want to test out is an html page or try a virtual ubuntu machine on your current system.
I use my 14.10 as a home media server, and use remotedesktop to control it with my other ubuntu system downstairs.
I haven't needed a reason to switch to the ubuntu server yet myself.

Comment: I don't want to set a permanent server on home. I'm just trying to make it a server just for 2 or 3 hours only. And then what is Ubuntu Server? isn't it used to control Servers?

Comment: maybe try a live cd with ubuntu server loaded up, if you are comfortable in the command line so that you may host whatever you are testing out.

Comment: I'm still thinking you might get a better solution if you can describe in a bit more detail what exactly you want to accomplish with your current ubuntu installation, because a software alternative might be your best answer.
As I don't see very much purpose in setting up a temp server, config all the settings (could be extensive depending on your demands) just to erase it all a few hours later.